# MongoError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
MongoError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll
    at Function.MongoError.create (E:\ecom\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
    at toError (E:\ecom\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:139:22)
    at E:\ecom\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1059:67
    at E:\ecom\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
POST /product/572a35ce194328dc20bfb7c7 500 3099.572 ms - 665
```

Comment: i m not able to find $pushAll command in the specified file path:E:\ecom\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js

Comment: `$pushAll` is now deprecated and will not work with the newer mongodb versions... Use  [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/update/each/) instead

Comment: with what should i replace $each??coz in the specified file path i used push not $pushAll

Comment: err = new MongoError(options.message || options.errmsg || options.$any|| "n/a");                                                                                                                   this is the line giving error.............how to fix it??

Comment: resolved it.............thanks@Anthony

Comment: How did you solve the error? Because I am struggling to understand why I get it because I do not use $pushAll anywhere in my code